# clicking function in android

Tags: android

how to connect to email while clicking on button in android

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Please describe in more detail what you're trying to do.

Comment: How to answer your question while limited information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send something by email your best bet is to use `ACTION_SEND`. Then it can be picked-up by email app, Twitter app, Facebook app - depending on what apps user may have on his device

```
private void sendBy(final String title, final String text) {
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title);
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send this job by"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking at two separate questions.

How do you link a button on the XML layout into your code.  What you're wanting is an "onClickListener".

There are many tutorials and example code out on the web.
http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/14/implementing-listeners-in-your-android-java-application/

(The important thing to note is the lines 14-27 in that example.  That code gets executed when that button is clicked.

Then you're wanting to do Email.  There are a a few protocols you're going to need to know about.  SMTP is the protocol for sending messages.  POP3 and IMAP are used for getting messages.

Look up on google for Android SMTP and Android IMAP examples / tutorials.

That should get you started.